# Touchpad not working on MSi U130 after login in

Tags: touchpad

I have just upgraded to 11.10 but my MSi U130's touchpad doesn't work after login to 11.10. It works fine in the login screen where one types password to login. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there an external mouse? And have you installed kde in the past?

Comment: Yes, I am using an external mouse, but don't want to carry around all the time.

Answer (score 13):

The problem could be caused by an IRQ conflict between your mouse and your touchpad. This is a Linux kernel bug (at least in 2.6.28) and as such it affects most distributions. An easy way to recover both mouse and touchpad functionality without having to restart your X server is restarting the mouse driver. Run the following commands in a terminal window:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

source: [Dealing with mouse and touchpad freezes in Linux](http://xpapad.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/dealing-with-mouse-and-touchpad-freezes-in-linux/)

I am currently using Linux kernel 3.0.0-16, so if this is indeed the same bug, I'm surprised it's still there.

Comment: What is this actually doing? Removing the overall mouse module or just the PS-2 mouse module?

Comment: Bookmarked because this happens almost daily to me.

Answer (score 8):

Installing the synaptics utility and changing settings didn't work for me.  I found something that fixed it in a comment in a Bug report

1. Install dconf-tools (`dconf-tools` in synaptic package manager or dconf Editor in the Ubuntu Software Center)
2. Launch it, it's called "dconf Editor" (It's in the **System** group if you use filters)
3. Find the setting **touchpad-enabled** in `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad/` and enable it.
4. Quit the editor and you're done.

Note, this did not require a restart or logout/in for me, the touchpad started working straight away.

My laptop is an MSI i7 running 64 bit Ubuntu 11.10, upgraded from a clean install of ll.04

Comment: I had to lick the "Set to default" button to make the change permanent.