# After logging on, the touchpad stops working

Tags: touchpad

I have a Dell latitude E6420 laptop.  After logging in to my account, the touchpad doesn't work and the pointer is frozen.  It only doesn't work for 1 account.  The guest account is fine.  Anyone know how to resolve this.  I saw another post for the mouse, but the question was closed without a solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Found this post helpful:  [Touchpad not working on MSi U130 after login in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66907/touchpad-not-working-on-msi-u130-after-login-in)

On the Dell Latitude, I just had to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to re-enable the touchpad.

It must have been pressed accidentally when I was moving my laptop.