# Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

I am using Dell Inspiron 15R 5521 laptop.
It had Ubuntu 12.04 installed at time of purchase.
Everything was working fine.Then i installed windows in it and now i have removed windows and installed Ubuntu 14.04 .
The problem i am facing is that my touchpad is not detected in it.
I searched on google , askUbuntu but could not get solution to my problem.
Also i went through this link (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) but it did not help.
Can you please help me here.
Let me know what other information is required here.

Thanks.

Comment: try with installing `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`. If it is already installed, purge and reinstall.

Comment: I tried that too.It did not work .. :(

Answer (score 1):

My research indicate that your laptop has a [SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201208-11540/components/)

Execute the following command

```
xinput list
```

You should see a output like the following

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer            id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1025   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard           id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                             id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                          id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

To enable the touch pad

```
xinput set-prop [device id] "Device Enabled" 1
```

You can do a following to check the properties

```
xinput --watch-props [device number]
```

You also can try

```
lsmod 
lsmod | grep mouse (Check the if the touchpad is loaded)

sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Also you can take look at following post too.

[Touchpad not working on MSi U130 after login in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66907/touchpad-not-working-on-msi-u130-after-login-in/72610#72610)

Comment: I recommend `xinput --list-props` instead to check the device's properties, so the process ends up.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [Touchpad under 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working)

#### Solution #1

1. Modify the GRUB file with a text editor (nano works too)

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Locate this line in the grub file

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```
3. Replace it with the following:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
   ```
4. Save the GRUB file and run the update

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Shutdown / reboot for the changes to take effect.

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```

#### Solution #2

1. Modify the GRUB file with a text editor (nano works too)

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Locate this line in the grub file

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```
3. Replace it with the following: (**ONLY DIFFERENCE FROM SOLUTION 1**)

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
   ```
4. Save the GRUB file and run the update

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Shutdown / reboot for the changes to take effect.

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```