# Ubuntu 18.04: Acer Predator Helios 300 cant find Touchpad Drivers

Tags: drivers, 18.04, mouse, touchpad

I have an Acer Predator Helios 300. The touchpad works in Ubuntu under the **"Basic"** Mode in the BIOS Settings. But on changing it to **"Advanced"**, it does not work.

I have tried installing i2c-tools, 
I have followed the directions in:
[Touchpad and typing](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383952)
[Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506338/touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04)
[Touchpad under 16.04 not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763763/touchpad-under-16-04-not-working), which contains directions given under many such questions.

In dconf-editor, there is no touchpad in: **org/gnome/desktop/peripherials/**

Answer (score 0):

I got same when I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04, Finally, I got all working :

TouchPad: In BIOS change touchpad option from advanced to basic,

And Try to Install Ubuntu 18.04 and then install Nvidia drivers and it

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned in my question. But I need it to work under "Advanced" Mode because I also use Windows with it, and the touchpad works very poorly then

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me on my Acer Predator Helios 300 running Ubuntu 18.04 (5.0.0-36-generic) when all else did not-

**Check if the solution works**
Try running the following command after waking up from suspend when your trackpad is not working- `/sbin/rmmod i2c_hid && /sbin/modprobe i2c_hid`.
If this makes your trackpad work, follow the below steps to create an automatic solution that runs this everytime you wake up from suspend.

**Permanent Solution**
 1. Create `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad`
 2. Open the above file and edit it, `sudo vi /lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad`
 3. Save the following content in the file-

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
  post)
    /sbin/rmmod i2c_hid && /sbin/modprobe i2c_hid 
  ;;
esac
```

4. Make it executable- `chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/touchpad`

This basically restarts the i2c_hid device upon waking up from suspend.

Courtesy: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526488/283735